# Row Editor sending wrong Date

Tags: extjs4.1

Recently I have upgrade my Ext version from 4.0.7 to 4.1.1

In my model I have defined like

```
{name : 'StartDate',type: 'date' ,dateFormat: 'time'},
```

My Grid Column is

```
{
id: 'StartDateID',
width: 180,
text: 'Start Date',
dataIndex: 'StartDate',
renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y'),
editor:{
    allowBlank: true,
    xtype:'datefield',
    format:'m/d/Y',
    editable: true},
sortable: false, groupable: false }
```

On Edit I am doing

```
My_Grid.on('edit', function(editor, e) {
```

e.store.sync();
}

After clicking on Update I used to get [with Ext 4.0.7 ] date value as

```
2012-08-04T00:00:00
```

but after upgrade with 4.1.1 I am getting date value as

```
310008e
```

Which I am not understanding.

My date is in this format

```
1346351400000
```

Can you please suggest me what is missing here? Or else how to get proper date after clicking update button from RowEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition is incorrect, if you want your desired format it should be like:

```
{name : 'StartDate',type: 'date' ,dateFormat: 'U'},
```

'time' is not in the documentation, the only reason you could actually be using 'time' is if it is a custom type you have created, which is probably not the case.

Comment: If I used the dateFormat as "U" can am getting the date in Unix format after clicking on Update button from Row Editor. But on Grid , I am getting blank value instade of Date.  I want to achieve both at time i.e. row Editor should return value in readable format and also on Gird I should be able to display date in "d/m/y" format

Comment: Actually, dateFormat: "time" is valid. It's defined as part of Ext.data.Types.DATE. The "U" format is different; "time" is in milliseconds since 01/01/70, "U" is in seconds. @Atul, where are you getting the "310008e" from? The store, the writer output, the debugger?

Comment: I get this when I am clicking on the update button from the Row editor.

Comment: Not sure how to fix this, but I believe what's happening is that the default format for date submission has changed for committing a model to the server, and there is no way to change it when using the model designation.